# Format ps STIME on Linux

Tags: linux, ps

I recently moved to Linux from HP-UX and I noticed that STIME of a process is in "MonthDate" format(e.g. Apr21) while on HP-UX it was "Month Date"(e.g. Apr 21). There is no space between month and date. Is there a way to get a space between month and date?

**HP-UX:**

```
root 16773     1  1  Jul 15  ?        67:23 /opt/ssh/sbin/sshd
```

**Linux:**

```
oper     24494 23075  0 Apr21 ?        00:00:00 sshd: oper@pts/8
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The option `bsdstart` should help.

You can use adding the needed options to the `ps` command with `-o`.

like `ps -e -o user,pid,ppid,stime,bsdstart,tty,cmd`

```
USER         PID    PPID STIME  START TT       CMD
root        1669       1 Apr21 Apr 21 ?        /usr/libexec/upowerd
binarys+    2605    2600 Apr21 Apr 21 pts/0    zsh
```

Comment: bsdstart will definitely get you the output you are after. Incidentally, the HPUX ps personality does not use bsdstart but uses stime.

git blame says its been like that since 2002 when I imported Albert's procps 010114 so we have had it that way for a while. My HPUX vague knowledge (which predates 2002) says there was a big change around that time so maybe there are two formats?

Answer (score 1):

This may help you, print the columns and format the date at will:

```
ps aux | awk '{ c="date +%d%b"; c | getline x; close(c); print $1, $2, $3, x }'
```